# About 1.8% of users getting ajax requests errors with status 0 - might be a connectivity issue

Tags: connection

I've been refered here after SO user downvoted me. [This is my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119254/about-1-8-of-users-getting-ajax-requests-errors-with-status-0) so please read it and the comments (not sure if I should copy the old question or refer, so let me know if its ok).

I'm trying to understand what might be the causes to that and what should I do next to get a better understanding of what the hell happens.

Some info about the servers:
User -> Cloudflare (Pro user, WAF is off) -> Varnish server -> Nginx server with PHP

Varnishlog and Nginx errors logs have nothing interesting to tell me, no 500 errors or any of that

Thanks!

Comment: Stand up a client testbed, on a network far removed from your production environment. at 1.8%, it shouldn't take long to trigger the error, after which you can grab client logs. You could even grab packet captures.

Comment: Hi thanks. Not sure what is a client testbed. I googled a bit and found TestRail, can this be an appropriate tool for that?

Comment: You need to capture the error that your clients are seeing, along with a packet capture. "Client testbed" is just a generic term for "standing up a bunch of clients which you can use to hammer away at your webapp until you trigger the error".